# What did Gygax and Arneson base the Bag of Holding on?

Tags: magic-items, dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

The Bag of Holding has been a staple of D&D since the game started. The idea of a bag that can hold more than it's physical capacity (and weight less than the it holds) can also be seen in other places, like Santa's toy bag.

Where did the original designers of Dungeons & Dragons (Gygax, Arneson, etc.) get their idea of a Bag of Holding come from? Please provide evidence of your answer by citing a source that ties it back to the game designers.

Comment: This question is starting to get out of hand.  Speculation is not a valid answer to a question of this type; if that means it goes unanswered that's fine. All the answers-in-comments and probably the answers-as-pure-speculation are going to be deleted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In *Playing at the World*, historian Jon Peterson suggests that the bag of holding was adapted from Jack Vance's Dying Earth:

> *Dungeons & Dragons* offers the over-encumbered adventurer some respite in the form of a Bag of Holding, which can contain 10,000 gold pieces worth of weight while only requiring 300 gold pieces worth of strength to carry; a likely inspiration for this item comes from the strange “bronze ring” (a metal circle large enough to fit a man through, rather than just a finger) containing its own private space belonging to Liane the Wayfarer in Vance’s Dying Earth.

Comment: @KRyan  Just to play devil's advocate, "a likely inspiration" is Peterson making an educated guess.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast An actual historian making a statement in an actually published book is a far cry better than anything else on this page.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be the first element of Vance's novels that was adapted into D&D, either. Vancian magic, anyone?

Answer (score 9):

Even without a source, the Bag of Holding is a necessary tool for D&D characters. Like Voltaire's view of God, "if [it] did not exist, it would be necessary to invent [it]."

Figuring out how to get hundreds of pounds of treasure home from the dungeon is fun at most once. The Bag of Holding lets the game abstract away encumbrance for items not in active use.

It seems likely that the aesthetics of the Bag of Holding are inspired by [trope examples](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BagOfHolding) like Felix the Cat's magic bag, Santa Claus's sack, or Gurgi's wallet from Prydain. However, the impetus for its invention is probably Gygax or another early GM going, "Screw it, I'll give them a magic bag so we stop wasting time on the logistics of cargo."

Comment: Apparent speculation makes for a weak answer. This site seeks answers that *are* correct, not merely *could be* correct. This answer would be vastly improved by citing anything that suggests that the view that the *bag of holding* was born of necessity has been suggested by an actual designer of D&D, rather than just being what you surmise.

Comment: @BlueFootedBooby It is acceptable that no one can answer a question; the appropriate response to that situation is to *leave it unanswered.* That’s OK. We close questions that are literally *unanswerable* (one cannot even imagine what a proper answer would hypothetically look like), but not ones that are merely *hard*. Just because they’re hard does not give anyone carte blanche to ignore our standards for answering.

Comment: Also, per the edit to the question, this is no longer an answer to the question asked.